# Pandas group by and sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to sum a column after groupby,

Here is my Data

```
|Day       |SMSsNumber|ShortCode|
|----------|----------|---------|
|2020-08-25|647       |26243    |
|2020-08-25|6,396     |76973    |
|2020-08-25|16,615    |51532    |
|2020-08-25|315       |59230    |
|2020-08-25|4,732     |30210    |
|2020-08-25|209       |32261    |
|2020-08-25|7         |54835    |
```

I already grouped by Date, but i need to sum the SMSsNumber column.

This is what I getting

```
|Day       |SMSsNumber|Codes|
|----------|----------|-----|
|2020-08-25|647       |26243|
|          |6,396     |76973|
|          |16,615    |51532|
|          |315       |59230|
|          |4,732     |30210|
|          |209       |32261|
|          |7         |54835|
```

And I need to get the info like this:

```
|Day       |SMSsNumber|Codes|
|----------|----------|-----|
|2020-08-25|28921     |26243|
|          |          |76973|
|          |          |51532|
|          |          |59230|
|          |          |30210|
|          |          |32261|
|          |          |54835|
```

This is my code

```
read = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
group_day = read.groupby(['Day','SMSsNumber']).sum()
group_day.to_html('test.html')
print(group_day.head())
```

:c

Comment: If those commas are really in the column values, then make sure to make it a number rather than a string or you won't be able to `sum()` it correctly

Answer (score 1):

Do not group by SMSsNumber:

```
read.groupby('Day').sum()
```

If there are other columns that you want to avoid, select the columns explicitly:

```
read.groupby('Day')[['SMSsNumber','ShortCode']].sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
group_day = read.groupby(['Day','SMSsNumber']).sum()
```

In the code above, you're grouping by two columns.

What you want is to group by the first, and sum the second:

```py
group_day = read.groupby(['Day'])['SMSsNumber'].sum()
```

If you don't specify which column to perform the sum on, you'll get the sum for all columns supporting the operation.