# What's the equivalent of SELECT SUM() GROUP BY on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

**Question:** 
I'd like to do the equivalent of a `SELECT SUM(x) ... GROUP BY y` on a Pandas dataframe.

**What I've found**
Unfortunately [there seems to be the misconception, that `df.groupby(["x"]).sum()` will do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63711295/pandas-group-by-and-sum).

**Problem**
`df2 = df.groupby(["x"]).sum().keys()` will not list *x* as key anymore. I.e. `df2["x"]` will raise an exception.

Comment: ``df.groupby('y', as_index = False).x.sum()``

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `.reset_index()`

So you need:

```
df.groupby(["x"]).sum().reset_index()
```